# Output Error from SimpliPy in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, simplify

I am trying to simplify a polygon layer of parliamentary constituencies in Kenya using [SimplyPy](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/simplipy/) in QGIS and appear to be getting an erroneous result.

The method is working for most of the polygons but there are 10 or so which are disappearing in the final result. Interestingly, the polygons which are disappearing all have similar object IDs (from 280-290 - there are 290 altogether) and so it could be due to SimpliPy having a limit of only 280 polygons at once... (I hope not!). Before and after below:

[image]

I have included a link to my shapefile [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B46iygwVJNx9WGhLZzg3WmZONFU).

My question is: **Why are my polygons disappearing in the final output?**

Comment: Have you tried running this on the same shapefile with only 280 polygons? Are you encountering the issue with other shapefiles with more than 280 polygons?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. I do not have any other shapefiles with >280 polygons nor have I tried to reduce the number of polygons in this one. I will try not and edit this post on the outcome.

Comment: @TaylorDay - Could you provide a screenshot of the options you used for the plugin please?

Comment: Hi - I could provide a screenshot... but I tried numerous tolerance parameters and snap precisions to no avail. Options I selected were: Douglas-Peucker; first to last (any tolerance gave the same output); prevent shape removal ticked; use topology ticked (any snap precision gave the same output). Latest version 0.52.